# Run Chrome with a different user -Katalon and groovy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I am using katalon and groovy for test automation.

We have a module where I need to login with different users and test the functionality.I am looking to automate the regression testing of this module but the challenge for me here is to automate the login as different user scenario, also I couldn't find any scripts that support different user login for groovy or java .

https://forum.katalon.com/t/run-chrome-with-a-different-user-than-the-one-who-started-katalon/15421/7

Please advise.

```
public IWebDriver CreateNewBrowserFor(string Who)
{
    //Decide which of Selenium nodes we want to connect to 
    string CapabilitiesOfTargetUser;
    if(Who.Equals("user1"))
    {
        //We need to control a browser for user1 on his node
        CapabilitiesOfTargetUser = "platform=Mac;browserName=firefox";
    }
    else if(Who.Equals("me"))
    {
        //We need to control a browser for me on my node
        CapabilitiesOfTargetUser = "platform=WINDOWS";
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    //Create a Selenium DesiredCapabilities object that contains our choosen capabilities
    Dictionary<string, object> RequestedCapabilities = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
    string[] CapabilitiesArray = CapabilitiesOfTargetUser.Split(';');
    foreach(string KeyValuePair in CapabilitiesArray)
    {
        string key = KeyValuePair.Split('=').First().Trim();
        string value = KeyValuePair.Split('=').Last().Trim();
        RequestedCapabilities[key] = value;
    }
    DesiredCapabilities Capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(RequestedCapabilities);

    //Create the RemoteWebDriver. Selenium's hub will ensure that this RemoteWebDriver is
    //actually controlling a new browser on the correct machine
    return  new RemoteWebDriver
    (
         new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
       , Capabilities
       , new TimeSpan(0, 0, 50)
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried, so we can work from there.

Comment: @cfrick i have updated the link which i refered

Comment: Please add the relevant code here.  It might be a tad much to ask to read through that wall of text from your xpost.